# IDs not outputting in order, after using group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql, string, csv

i am having trouble matching the IDs of size_categories table with sizes table.
This is the query

```
select
    size_categories.size_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(sizes.name) as size_name
from `subcategories`
inner join `categories` on `categories`.`id` = `subcategories`.`categories_id`
inner join `size_categories` on `size_categories`.`categories_id` = `categories`.`id`
inner join `sizes` on FIND_IN_SET(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id) > '0'
where
    `subcategories`.`id` = '15'
group by
    `subcategories`.`name`,
    `size_categories`.`size_id`
```

The result is

```
size_id    size_name

4,2,1       2m,8m,4m
```

The problem is 4 is actually the id of 4m, and 1 is of 2m. How can i get that in order?
Please Help. Thank You

Comment: Why don't you normalize `size_id`? And please stop quoting numerics like `'0'`

Comment: yes, i should. but its getting complex and funny.

Comment: Less complex and funny than your current solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `order by` in `group_concat()`. I think you want:

```
group_concat(
    sizes.name 
    order by find_in_set(sizes.id, size_categories.size_id)
) as size_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ordering by the leading digits of the sizes:

```
select
    size_categories.size_id,
    GROUP_CONCAT(
        sizes.name
        ORDER BY CAST(REGEXP_SUBSTR(sizes.name, '^[0-9]+') AS UNSIGNED)
    ) as size_name
```

This assumes you are using MySQL 8+.  The above is the only easy way to do this which comes to mind, given that we don't necessarily know how many digits the size might have, or which letters might be following the numeric size.